# xbuild SignAndroidPackage keystore for Xamarin Android projects

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to create a headless build automation system for my Android app developed using c# (Xamarin).

I have successfully created all the automation scripts required. The only issue that I am facing is when I need to build a `signed` Android apk. In my build script, I call:

```
xbuild $ANDROID_PROJECT_FILE /t:PackageForAndroid /p:Configuration=Release
```

This would just create an unsigned `apk`. To sign it, I tried changing target to `SignAndroidPackaage`, i.e.

```
xbuild $ANDROID_PROJECT_FILE /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release
```

In this case however, the build process tries to get the default/debug keystore as follows:

```
Target _Sign:
    Tool /usr//bin/keytool execution started with arguments: -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "/Users/blasheep/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore" 
    androiddebugkey, Nov 10, 2015, PrivateKeyEntry, 
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <>
    Tool /usr//bin/jarsigner execution started with arguments: -keystore "/Users/blasheep/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin/Release//com.alpha.beta-Signed-Unaligned.apk /Users/blasheep/project/apps/Android/Project/Project/obj/Release/android/bin/com.alpha.beta.apk androiddebugkey 
    jar signed.
```

The **question** is simple: I have a custom keystore that I want to use with the internal `jarsigner`. For example:

```
xbuild $ANDROID_PROJECT_FILE /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release /keystore:/Users/blasheep/something.keystore
```

Is there a way to do this? If not, how can I use a headless build for signed Android build automation? I don't want to use rake or any other tools but the default set of tools on the Mac (including xbuild/xamarin, etc).

Comment: We have done it two ways, 1) placing the <AndroidSigningKeystore> elements into the `.csproj` but adding <AndroidSigningStorePass> (or injecting it before the release build) is a security issue for some... 2) Directly call `jarsigner` and `zipalign` instead of using MSBuild/xbuild to call those tools for that step (this is want we normally do for headless/cloud builds)

Comment: Thanks. I think I found it already. What you are referring to is this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/. I think?

I am still using xbuild with `PackageForAndroid` and after that i am using `jarsigner` and `zipalign`. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, I think that is the link (SO does not like the commas that are in it..)... I think I just lifted cmds the first time from the many rake scripts out there.. there are also several cmd and powershell versions floating around... in the end it is just two cmds ;-)

Comment: #FeelsGoodMan. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps add that first comment as an answer.